# BeautifulSoup selecting one child from an array of output children

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, children

I'm trying to scrape one of Yahoo's stock tables. I want to print out the table values (which works) for each row.:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import urllib2
import re

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/predefined/undervalued_growth_stocks"

table_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = bsoup(table_page,'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table')

table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    tdrow = [i.text for i in td]
    print tdrow
```

This works fine, and produces (for each row), this:

```
[u'AMAT', u'Applied Materials, Inc.', u'58.71', u'+1.09', u'+1.89%', u'7.364M', u'10.282M', u'62.614B', u'20.87', u'']
[u'PK', u'Park Hotels & Resorts Inc.', u'29.01', u'+0.34', u'+1.19%', u'628,369', u'1.216M', u'6.233B', u'2.49', u'']
```

What I would like to do is select the first child / element (the stock ticker, above "AMAT") so that I can pass it on.

If I use

```
print tdrow[0]
```

It creates an error

> IndexError: list index out of range

If I remove the indent from "print tdrow[0]", it works (I can specify [0] and get "PK", [1] and get "Applied Materials Inc.", but it only for the last row - I would like to use [0] for each row (within the "for tr in table_row" loop).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because the first row is empty (not sure why) so `print tdrow[0]` will throw an out of bounds. But then the rest of the rows are fine, so moving the print outside the loop will refer to the last row, which works.

So checking the row exists should solve.

This is the output I got when I ran your code exactly as it appears in the block above, note the empty first row.

```
[]
[u'AMAT', u'Applied Materials, Inc.', u'58.74', u'+1.12', u'+1.94%', u'7.725M', u'10.282M', u'62.64B', u'20.88', u'']
[u'WBA', u'Walgreens Boots Alliance, Inc.', u'70.885', u'+0.105', u'+0.148%', u'4.947M', u'7.65M', u'71.562B', u'17.90', u'']

.
.
.

[u'PLD', u'Prologis, Inc.', u'67.29', u'+0.85', u'+1.28%', u'841,231', u'1.969M', u'36.275B', u'20.17', u'']
[u'PK', u'Park Hotels & Resorts Inc.', u'29.01', u'+0.34', u'+1.19%', u'640,075', u'1.216M', u'6.233B', u'2.49', u'']
```

Comment: The first row is empty. I will see if I can fix that, maybe it works then. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I thought your question was about why the print would / wouldn't work - not why the row itself is empty.

Comment: It might be picking up a miscellaneous `td` tag somewhere - maybe search through the html and have a look at where all the tags appear. It might also be because the text inside that first tag is formatted incorrectly or something.

Comment: Yep, you were right. First row was empty (I am searching the tr for td, which excludes the first table row which are th).

Now that I use `find_all('th')` as well, the `print[0]` works within the loop. Thanks!